# Unexpected behaviour extracting values from array: all values are 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, floating-point

Using `tensorflow.js` on Google Chrome I noticed an unexpected behaviour extracting values from an array.

The code is very simple:

```js
console.log(boxes); // Array of 1200 positions.

let order = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    order.push(boxes[i*4 + 1]);
}

console.log(order); // Array of 10 positions with values from 'boxes'.
```

The source array `boxes` is the following:

[image]

The destination array `order` is the following:

[image]

When I copy values from the original array `boxes`, all the values in the `order` array are 2. I tried to parse the values to a string, but the result is the same:

[image]

Tested on Firefox and same result.

Why does this happen?

Comment: From your screenshot, it is clearly visible, that the array before expanding it was as you would expect, yet changed before you expanded it.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It's right. Thank you.